# How to use static block to initialize spring hibernate query function

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc, static

I am new to Spring Hibernate, so I am having this problem that cause by a function that initialize in a static block.

This is my DAO class:

```
private static HibernateTemplate hibernateTemplate;
public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
    hibernateTemplate = new HibernateTemplate(sessionFactory);
}

static{
    loadAllProvince();
}
public static void loadAllProvince ()  {
    List regionList = hibernateTemplate.find("FROM regions");

    if (regionList.size() > 0 ) {           
       for (int i=0; i<regionList.size(); i++) {                
          Object[] obj = (Object[]) regionList.get(i) ;
          mapRegion.put(obj[1].toString(), obj[0].toString());                  
       }                        
    }   
 }
```

This is the bean configuration in my applicationContext.xml:

```
<bean id="regionDAOBean" class="com.dao.RegionDAO">
   <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactoryBean"/> 
</bean>
```

When I run my application, the exception say:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'regionDAOBean' defined in class path resource [applicationContext.xml]: 
Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
```

It was working find until I initialize the function in the static block, so what should I do in order to initialize the function in static block?

Comment: why are you making HibernateTemplate static?  `loadAllProvince();` will be called before the  sessionFactory is injected because static function happen before and instance of the bean is created.

Comment: It is because I create the static function, so I change it to static too. Is there any issue with this or should I remove the static?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is caused (as jax suggested) that the static method `loadAllProvince()` is executed before the sessionFactory is injected. However I would rather make `loadAllProvince()` non-static and make it called after the bean properties are populated, e.g.

```
<bean id="regionDAOBean" class="com.dao.RegionDAO" init-method="loadAllProvince">
   <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactoryBean"/> 
</bean>
```

see http://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-init-method-and-destroy-method-example/ for more details.

Answer (score 2):

I would simply make use of `@PostConstruct` (and get rid of the `init` method):

```
@PostConstruct
public void loadAllProvince () {
   ...
}
```

> The JSR-250 @PostConstruct and @PreDestroy annotations are generally
>   considered best practice for receiving lifecycle callbacks in a modern
>   Spring application. Using these annotations means that your beans are
>   not coupled to Spring specific interfaces. For details see Section
>   5.9.6, “@PostConstruct and @PreDestroy”.
>
> If you don't want to use the JSR-250 annotations but you are still
>   looking to remove coupling consider the use of init-method and
>   destroy-method object definition metadata.

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html

The problem is that the static block is called before Spring has had the opportunity to complete bean initialization (as @sodik pointed out). This is when `@PostConstruct` comes in handy as it tells Spring to call this method once the bean has been fully initialized.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you really want is to use the init-method:

```
<bean id="regionDAOBean" class="com.dao.RegionDAO" init-method="init">
   <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactoryBean"/> 
</bean>




private HibernateTemplate hibernateTemplate;
public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
    hibernateTemplate = new HibernateTemplate(sessionFactory);
}

public void init() throws Exception {
    loadAllProvince();
}

public void loadAllProvince ()  {
    List regionList = hibernateTemplate.find("FROM regions");

    if (regionList.size() > 0 ) {           
       for (int i=0; i<regionList.size(); i++) {                
          Object[] obj = (Object[]) regionList.get(i) ;
          mapRegion.put(obj[1].toString(), obj[0].toString());                  
       }                        
    }   
 }
```